# Macro auto run on Multi sheet workbook based on specific cell "value"

Tags: excel, macros, vba

There is a lot of discussion about using VBA code to auto run a Macro based on the "value" of a cell.  What I need help with is writing code to auto initiate a Macro based on the "VALUE" of cell A1 (SHEET 2) (On/Off).  Sheet 1 has an Active X button that is linked to a cell on Sheet 1 then Sheet 2 uses an `=Sheet1(cell)` formula, then I used an `=if` formula to change true/false to on/off.(Sheet 2) When cell "A1" changes between on and off I would like the Macro to initiate.

```
Sub H1TL0()
'
' 
H1TL0 Macro
'

'


Sheets("LASER LOG").Select
Rows("5:5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Sheets(" LASER WORKSHEET").Select
Range("G78").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("LASER LOG").Select
Range("B5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets(" LASER WORKSHEET").Select
Range("G80").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("LASER LOG").Select
Range("C5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets(" LASER WORKSHEET").Select
Range("G83").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("LASER LOG").Select
Range("D5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("F14").Select
Sheets(" LASER WORKSHEET").Select
End Sub
```

I have run the Macro H1TL0 and it works fine.

P.S.  I am brand new to VBA (as in 3 days new) so please bear with my ignorance.

Comment: You can use `Select ... Case` statement and then `Call` the desired Macro (Sub-ruotine).

Comment: Thank you for editing my question. I will do my best to learn the formating styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
 'Place below sub in [ThisWorkbook] code pane  
 Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
     If StrComp(ActiveSheet.Name, "Dashboard") = 0 Then

       If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Cell Value" Then
       'Put Condition here. if there are multiple then add elsif
        End If
     End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. It took some studying to figure it all out, but it now works.